# How to pass vector as reference in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to pass my vector "myStaffs" from Team Class by reference to Manage Class because I want to manipulate the data of staffs and sort them. How do I pass it by reference?

**Header Staff**

```
    #ifndef STAFF_H
    #define STAFF_H
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <string>


    class Staff
    {
        public:
            Staff();
            Staff(int, int, int, int);
            ~Staff();

            static int genRanNum(int);
            static Staff* createStaff(int);
            const int getSize();

        private:
            int staSkills1,staSkills2,staSkills3;
            int staId;

            //int staDeptAsigned;
            //std::string staName;
    };

    #endif
```

**CPP Staff**

```
#include "Staff.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Staff::Staff():
    staId(0),
    staSkills1(0),
    staSkills2(0),
    staSkills3(0)
{
}

Staff::Staff(int id, int s1, int s2, int s3):
    staId(id),
    staSkills1(s1),
    staSkills2(s2),
    staSkills3(s3)
{
}
Staff *Staff::createStaff(int s)
{
    Staff *staff = new Staff();
    staff->staId = s;
    staff->staSkills1 = genRanNum(10);
    staff->staSkills2 = genRanNum(10);
    staff->staSkills3 = genRanNum(10);

    return staff;
}
int Staff::genRanNum(int num)
{
    return 1+(rand()%num);
}

Staff::~Staff()
{
}
```

**Header Team**

```
#ifndef TEAM_H
#define TEAM_H
#include "Staff.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;

class Team: public Staff
{
    public:
        Team();
        ~Team();

    private:
        vector<Staff *> myStaffs;
};

#endif // TEAM_H
```

**CPP Team**

```
#include "Team.h"

const int SIZE = 30;
Team::Team():
    myStaffs(SIZE)
{
    for(int iStaff = 0; iStaff <= SIZE; iStaff++)
    {
        myStaffs[iStaff] = createStaff(iStaff);
    }
}

Team::~Team()
{     
}
```

**Header Manage**

```
#ifndef OPTIONS_H
#define OPTIONS_H
#include "Team.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;


class Manage
{
    public:
        Manage();
        ~Manage();



    private:
        // vector 
};
```

**CPP Manage**

```
#include "Manage.h"

Manage::Manage()
{
}

Manage::~Manage()
{
}

#endif
```

Comment: Um, maybe use a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)?

Comment: `vector<Staff *> myStaffs;` smells 5 miles against the current wind direction! Rather use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to be stored in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple you pass it as you would pass any other object by reference

```
int sortEmployee(std::vect<Staff *> &staffList> {
 // ... code to sort Employee
}
```

and you can call it like below

```
vector<Staff *> myStaffs
result = sortEmployee(myStaffs);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as

```
#include <vector>

void myVectorManglingFun(std::vector<Staff *> &myStaff) //notice the &
{
    //do something here
}
```

If you don't need to modify the vector, then always use a const reference.

```
void myVectorReadingFun(const std::vector<Staff *> &myStaff)
```